# Terminal printing 0 when running web scraping code

Tags: python, web-scraping

Why is it just printing `0` when I run this code?
I am trying to print the articles' title, link, and date.  Is the .aspx link possibly a problem for this method?
I originally was trying an rss version https://codeburst.io/building-an-rss-feed-scraper-with-python-73715ca06e1f and changing that to an individual website because the rss doesn't give me the info I actually need.  Thanks for the help!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url= 'https://tymeinc.com/newsroom/press-releases/default.aspx'


def news(url):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, features= 'xml')
        articles = soup.findAll('blog_section')
        print(len(articles))
        for a in articles:
            
            title = a.find('blog_title').text
            link = a.find('blog_link').text
            published = a.find('module_date-time').text
            description = a.find('blog_short-body').text
            article = {'blog_title': title,'blog_link': link,'module_date-time': published}
            articles.append(article)
            return print(url)
                
            return print(title)
            #return print(articles, "done")
    except Exception as e:
        print('The scraping job failed. See exception: ', e)
news(url)
```

Comment: It's returning 0 because the length of your articles is 0. That's also why it isn't returning anything else.

Comment: Your `for` loop always returns on the first iteration because you have `return print(url)`

Comment: `soup.findall("blog_section")` should be `soup.findall(class_="blog_section")`

Comment: And similar for all your `find()` calls.

Comment: @Barmar for some reason it is still returning 0.  Been struggling with it for a couple days.  Could it be that it's a .aspx page? It is clearly an issue with the `articles = soup.findall` part.

Comment: The site builds the content using JavaScript. You need to use Selenium WebDriver to execute it.